# Issue with Managed Platform Update on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ebs

I have several instances in a specific region of EC2 using EBS as well. Recently, I've started noticing some error logs caused by the Managed Platform Update. Here are the logs:

```
February 8, 2024 16:34:30 (UTC-3) INFO Deployment failed. Terminating new instances and temporary Auto Scaling group.
February 8, 2024 16:34:29 (UTC-3) ERROR Failed to deploy configuration.
February 8, 2024 16:34:29 (UTC-3) ERROR Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-auhbch5mnp-immutable-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBEIP].
February 8, 2024 16:34:29 (UTC-3) ERROR Creating EIP failed Reason: Resource handler returned message: "The maximum number of addresses has been reached. (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: c0f652a6-9c94-4d44-9077-ebf7f968c74a)" (RequestToken: 748926b3-cc81-1edf-d384-0ae944a36a0d, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
February 8, 2024 16:33:58 (UTC-3) INFO Immutable deployment policy enabled. Launching one instance with the new settings to verify health.
February 8, 2024 16:33:50 (UTC-3) INFO Environment update is starting.
February 8, 2024 16:33:49 (UTC-3) INFO Managed platform update is in-progress.
```

The issue is that I have 5 instances in the region (which seems to be the limit), but I don't want to delete any of them. I saw that it was possible to set the instances to deploy in "All at Once" mode, and that should be enough to prevent it from creating a new Auto Scaling Group and temporary instance, but nothing changed.

[image]

It still prints "immutable deployment policy enabled. Launching one instance with the new settings to verify health." when starting the update, even with the settings disabled. Did I misunderstand something, or is that really the case? Is the only solution to have only 4 instances per region to avoid the problem?